# Telegram Inline Bot - Can the Chat_id = username I send it?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot to which I give the username of the person I want it to send a message to.

Here's the code snippet that handles that

```
def inline_query(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    _, _ = User.get_user_and_created(update, context)
    is_verified: bool = is_seller_verified(update.inline_query.from_user.id)
    if is_verified:
        query = update.inline_query.query
        if len(query) == 0 or query[-1] != '.':
            print('Empty query, showing message to seller to type username of buyer')
            results = [
                InlineQueryResultArticle(
                    id='Noop',
                    title=noop_title,
                    input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(noop_description),
                    thumb_url='https://i.imgur.com/1tDhWge.png',
                    thumb_width=64,
                    thumb_height=64
                )
            ]
            update.inline_query.answer(results)
        elif len(query) > 1 and query.endswith('.'):
            buyer_username = query[:-1]
            emoji_hash = _random_emoji()
            seller_username: str = update.inline_query.from_user.username
            seller_tg_id: int = update.inline_query.from_user.id
            total_count, buyer_count = get_transaction_info(seller_tg_id, buyer_username)
            emoji_code: str = _emoji_password(seller_username, update.inline_query.from_user.id)  # TODO: make more complex
            verified_message_1 = verify_message_1 % (
                emoji_code,
                buyer_count,
                total_count,
                seller_username,
                _get_transaction_datetime(),
            )
            keyboard = [
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton(emoji_code, callback_data=GO_TO_CONFIRM),
                ],
                [
                    InlineKeyboardButton(emoji_hash, callback_data=GO_TO_RETRY),
                ],
            ]
            random.shuffle(keyboard)
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
            context.user_data['buyer_username'] = buyer_username
            print(buyer_username)
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=buyer_username, text=verified_message_1,
                                     reply_markup=reply_markup)
    else:
        keyboard = [
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton(text=start_verification_title, url='https://t.me/clientverify_bot'),
            ],
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=buyer_username,
                                 text=start_verification_message,
                                 reply_markup=reply_markup
                                 )
    return IMMUTABLE_STATE
```

As you can see I want the context.bot.send_message to go to the buyer username I give it, but I keep getting the error that chat is not found. The buyer_username variable is former from the query I pass to the bot after calling it i.e @Bot username

I read through some documentation and saw that the bot can't message users who didn't send a message to the bot. So I took another device with the username that I want the buyer_username variable to be and sent a message to the bot and then I tried running this but the same issue is there.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

No, from the `sendMessage` [documentation page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage):

> chat_id
>
> **Unique identifier** for the target chat **or** username of the target channel (in the format `@channelusername`)

So when sending to an user, the `chat_id` must be used.

When sending to a channel, you can use the `@` name.

---

In your case you'll need the `chat_id` from the received update.